# How to write an equation in sql?

Tags: sql, equations

I want to implement this equation in sql :

```
 f(x) = f(a) + (f(b)-f(a)) * (x-a)/(b-a)
```

My input is as following:

[image]

What I tried was:

```
select ((select CosValue from CosineTable where Angle=70) +
        ((select CosValue from CosineTable where Angle=75) -
         (select CosValue from CosineTable where Angle=70)) * (73-70) / (75-70)
from CosineTable;
```

It's showing me a syntax error.

Comment: do you need to return a result for each row, or are you looking at a specific row only?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I have to result only a single value

Comment: I am testing on SQLite

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one closing bracket `)`

Try this:

```
SELECT  ( ( SELECT  CosValue
        FROM    CosineTable
        WHERE   Angle = 70
      ) + ( ( SELECT    CosValue
              FROM      CosineTable
              WHERE     Angle = 75
            ) - ( SELECT    CosValue
                  FROM      CosineTable
                  WHERE     Angle = 70
                ) ) * ( 73 - 70 ) / ( 75 - 70 ) )
FROM    CosineTable;
```

But it only works if you always get a single value back in your Subselects.

Comment: Thank You. I ran the suggested edit but I got nothing in return despite the query running safely.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only one row per angle in your table, you query can be simplified by using a cross join:

```
select a70.cosvalue + (a75.cosvalue - a70.cosvalue) * (73-70) / (75-70))
from CosineTable a70
  cross join cosinetable a75
where a70.angle = 70
  and a75.angle = 75;
```

Comment: a70.cosvalue + ( a75.cosvalue - a70.cosvalue) * (73-70) / (75-70)

Comment: I dont think I am gonna need cross joins and will try to do it using select,from and where only

Comment: @user3740504: I don't see a solution without using a cross join. If you mean to use `from CosineTable a70, cosinetable a75` that is a cross join as well. Just written in the old, outdated join syntax